# Update binary file information

Tags: c#, c++

We have some binary files on windows platform.(dll,exe and arx) But the file version information is wrong.(Right click->Properties->Details. The File version or project version are not correct.) Some of them are written by C#，some are C++. Because we don't have the source code for some of them. Is there any way to change the information without re-compile these files?

**UPDATE**
can you recommend some command tools? I have more than 2 hundred files.I would like to write a script for it. Or can you give me some information about how to write such tool about it. I don't need too much function, only change the file version information.

Best Regards,

Comment: It is beyond me why on earth you even want to do this, especially since it is external packages. Welcome to maintainability nightmare.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker) or [XN Resource editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) to do that.

Comment: I edited the answer to provide links. This should explain better than me :)

Comment: Thanks, it's great. I have tried it, it's good. But can you recommend some command tools? I have more than 2 hundred files.I would like to write a script for it. Or can you give me some information about how to write such tool about it. I don't need too much function, only change the file version information. Thanks

Comment: Seems Reshack has a command line: [see this post about it](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=47720&st=0&p=357573&#entry357573)